# How to convert a tainted string into a string in nim

Tags: string, parsing

I want to read a file line by line in nim, like this:

```
for line in lines "myfile.txt":
  echo line
```

and now, in the loop (instead of the 'echo') I want to check if the line starts with, let's say 'abc'.
The problem is, that line is a TaintedString and the proc 'startsWith' I'd like to use, expects a string (not a TaintedString).
So the question is: What's the way to go, here? Should I convert the 'line' into a string and if yes, how? Or is there better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Oh. It seems to work with startsWith(..)
You can just call the proc from the string type.